# Dynamic programing - Coin Collecting Problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I finished the code algorithm of the **Coin-Collecting problem** based on *dynamic programing*, the problem is there is a (row x column) board which has coin placed on the upper left corner. A robot travels from the upper left to the bottom right corner collecting coins. The robot can only move from left to right or from top to down at a time. You have to find the maximum number of coins picked up by the robot and also print that particular path on which robot collects that max number of coins

How can I modify the algorithm to make the robot start from anywhere on the board and make some cells of the board invisible that means *the cell is inaccessible for the robot* ?
Like this image:

[image: board]

This is the function of getting the **max-coins-picked**

```
def max_coin_picked(self):

    # this algorithm follows the dynamic programing principle
    # for the coin_collecting problem
    for i in range(self.row):  # 5 rows
        for j in range(self.column):  # 6 column
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                self.gameBoard[i][j] = 0 + self.gameBoard[i][j]
            elif i == 0:
                self.gameBoard[i][j] = max(0, self.gameBoard[i][j - 1]) + self.gameBoard[i][j]
            elif j == 0:
                self.gameBoard[i][j] = max(self.gameBoard[i - 1][j], 0) + self.gameBoard[i][j]
            else:
                self.gameBoard[i][j] = max(self.gameBoard[i - 1][j], self.gameBoard[i][j - 1]) + self.gameBoard[i][
                    j]

    # getting the maximum value picked from the initialized values
    maxCoinPicked = self.gameBoard[self.row - 1][self.column - 1]
    return maxCoinPicked
```

and this is the function of the **path** the path appears in the board as stars

```
def path(self):

    # to accessing the values in the board in reverse mode
    row = self.row - 1  # 4
    column = self.column - 1  # 5

    # playing the first and last values in the board
    self.gameBoard[row][column] = '*'

    # finish when i=1 as first rew already assigned
    while row >= 1:
        if column != 0 and (self.gameBoard[row][column - 1] > self.gameBoard[row - 1][column]):  # leftward
            # moving to the left
            self.gameBoard[row][column - 1] = '*'
            column = column - 1
        else:
            # moving to the up
            self.gameBoard[row - 1][column] = '*'  # upward
            row = row - 1

    # the remaining cells path of the first row
    column = column - 1
    while column >= 0:
        self.gameBoard[0][column] = '*'
        column = column - 1

    return self.gameBoard
```

For more info check the code repository: [github code repo](https://github.com/MOoTawaty/CoinCollecting-Problem)

Comment: I want to transform this algorithm to a **Game** so need to modify it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making your board a 2-d array.  Like this for your example:

```
[[ 0, -1,  0,  1,  0, -1],
 [ 1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0],
 [ 0,  1,  0, -1,  1,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1],
 [-1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0]]
```

And now write a function that returns 2d arrays of both the most coins you can have, and the way you just got there.  That uses dynamic programming, like this:

```
def calculate_best_value_move (board):
    best_value = []
    best_move = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        best_value.append([])
        best_move.append([])
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] < 0:
                best_value[i].append(-1)
                best_move[i].append(None)
            else:
                move = 'Start'
                value = 0

                if 0 < j and value < best_value[i][j-1]:
                    value = best_value[i][j-1]
                    move = 'Right'

                if 0 < i and value < best_value[i-1][j]:
                    value = best_value[i-1][j]
                    move = 'Up'

                best_value[i].append(value + board[i][j])
                best_move[i].append(move)

    return (best_value, best_move)
```

And now you want a path from `best_move`, like this:

```
def find_best_path (best_move):
    end = (len(best_move)-1, len(best_move[-1])-1)
    reversed_path = [end]
    while True:
        i = reversed_path[-1][0]
        j = reversed_path[-1][1]
        move = best_move[i][j]
        if move == 'Start':
            break
        elif move == 'Right':
            reversed_path.append((i, j-1))
        elif move == 'Up':
            reversed_path.append((i-1, j))
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid move")

    return list(reversed(reversed_path))
```

And to run your example:

```
board = [
    [ 0, -1,  0,  1,  0, -1],
    [ 1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0],
    [ 0,  1,  0, -1,  1,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1],
    [-1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0]
]

best_value, best_move = calculate_best_value_move(board)
print(f"Best value is {best_value[-1][-1]} and path is {find_best_path(best_move)}")
```

Comment: thank U,
but I already did all of this and need to modify the algorithm for another reason as mentioned
for more info [check this](https://github.com/MOoTawaty/CoinCollecting-Problem)

Comment: @MohamedKhaled This version allows the robot to start anywhere on the board, and any cells marked with -1 are inaccessible to the robot.  Is that not what you asked for?